# engrain and internalize

Tags: word-choice

I wonder if dear natives could tell me if it is possible to substitute the bold words bellow with the italic words inside of the parentheses at the end of each sentence or not:

> - You have to **engrain** these beliefs in you. (*internalize*)
> - These beliefs have become **engrained** in the German people, over a period of many years. (*internalized*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Engraining** is the act of **strongly associating** a **belief** or **process** into a **system**.

> The American ethos becomes **engrained** through hard work.

**Internalizing** is having learned something so well and thoroughly that one can act using it **without thinking** i.e. it becomes automatic

> For athletes, movement is **internalized** by repetitive action called **muscle memory**.
>   He responded so quickly because he had **internalized** all his actions.

**Actions** and **beliefs** can usually only be **internalized** by **living things**.
Things become **internalized** by being **engrained** through learning.

Both **living things** and **ideals** can be **engrained by** or **with** *something*

Answer (score 1):

To me, the difference is more connotative.

**Internalizing** something carries an implication of understanding and comprehending it well. If I internalize a new idea in class, I learned it and understood it inside and out.

**Engraining**, on the other hand, doesn't carry that implication of understanding. You may understand it very well, but if it's engrained in you, you've basically carved it into you (which is the literal meaning of engrain). Maybe you repeated it 1000 times. Maybe you wrote it 1000 times. You can now recite it back to me. But you don't necessarily understand it inside and out - that isn't implied.

For example, in many religious households, beliefs are **engrained** into younger children. It would be strange to say that the kids have **internalized** the beliefs/teachings until they are much older. While they are kids and don't really understand exactly what's going on, they have simply memorized by repetition.